# why does rename nothing if old and new are the same?

Tags: linux, posix

My code was doing something like `link(link_target, hardlink_tmp); rename(hardlink_tmp, hardlink);`, with the intention to always have a valid dentry `hardlink`. I expected it to operate on `dentries`, and never leave a `hardlink_tmp` behind.

However, today I discovered many remaining `hardlink_tmp` files. Browsing `rename(2)` revealed:

```
If oldpath and newpath are existing hard links referring to the same file, then rename() does nothing, and returns a success status.
```

Slightly different wording in `rename(3p)`:

```
If the old argument and the new argument resolve to either the same existing directory entry or different directory entries for the same existing file, rename() shall return successfully and perform no other action.
```

Now I need to have a final `unlink(hardlink_tmp);` to remove a potentially stale dentry.

Why would that be desirable behavior?

Comment: To me it is not fully clear what you are doing. The function sequence `link(link_target, hardlink_tmp); rename(hardlink_tmp, hardlink);` does not explain why `hardlink` would be a link to `hardlink` unless `link_target` and `hardlink` are the same. I suggest to [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve by creating a link and then renaming it. Showing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) might also help to understand your use case.

Comment: @Bodo, it doesn't matter what they're doing in the first paragraph, they're asking about the behaviour of the system call and the rationale for that behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The restriction of renaming two names to the same file is in the POSIX spec too. [It says in the "rationale" section that](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html#tag_16_487_08):

> The specification that if old and new refer to the same file is
> intended to guarantee that:
>
> ```
> rename("x", "x");
> ```
>
> does not remove the file.

That's a bit simplistic, but given the rationale also mentions `rename()` as an alternative to `link()`+`unlink()`, it comes to mind  **--and I'm purely speculating here--** that a simple implementation might implement `rename(x, y)` as `unlink(y) && link(x, y) && unlink(x)`. But that would make the file disappear in the first step already if `x` and `y` are the same name.

It's also not enough to check if the two names are exactly the same string, since you might have cases like `rename("../foo/x", "x")` (when you're sitting at `foo/`), or worse, `rename("/dir/symlink/x", "x")` (where the symlink leads you back to `.`). It's not that easy to check if the two strings lead to the same filename, but calling `stat()` on both and checking the device and inode numbers to see if they're the same inode is easier. And then you also reject renames when they're two different filenames but the same file.

Which isn't to say that a modern smart implementation of `rename()` couldn't do it better, they way you expected, but it might have gotten codified based on How It Always Worked. (End speculation.)